# RegEx for dynamic expression replacement

Tags: regular-language

I need two regex for the following to cases:

1.
replace this

```
lr_start_transaction("001_0010_123-A1-a_text-or-numbers");
```

with this

```
lr_start_transaction(lr_eval_string("{scriptid}_0010_123-A1-a_text-or-numbers"));
```

2. replace this

```
lr_end_transaction("001_0010_123-A1-a_text-or-numbers",LR_AUTO);
```

with this

```
lr_end_transaction(lr_eval_string("{scriptid}_0010_123-A1-a_text-or-numbers"),LR_AUTO);
```

The part between the apostrophes is dynamic.

I'm using Notepad++ for the editing the code.

Could someone help me please???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We expect questions to include an attempt to solve the problem first, as we do not give out chunks of code. Please can you post what you have tried so far? People are then much more likely to help.

Comment: Addional explanation: I have to replace "lr_start_transaction("...");" with "lr_start_transaction(lr_eval_string("{scriptid}_..."));"

Comment: Sorry but I'm realy bad in regex so the things I tried aren't realy helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just search for see [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eD7qS1/2)

```
(\(".*?)(_.*")
```

and replace it by:

```
transaction(lr_eval_string("{scripted}\2)
```

Explanation:

```
(\(".*?) // look for (" in a non-greedy way (capture in \1)
(_.*")   // look for an underscore up to the next quote (capture in \2)


transaction(lr_eval_string("{scripted}\2)
// replace text, put back the capture group 2, then a closing parenthesis
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing currently but i want to save time (and avoid mistakes). That's why I'm looking for a regex to do just 1 replacement instead of 2. The last part is also different ")); instead of ");

Comment: Perfect: I used "lr_start_transaction(\(".*?)(_.*")" and "lr_start_transaction\(lr_eval_string\("{scripted}\2\)" in notepad and it works fine. I've just added a few escape signs. Thank you very much!